# how to get jquery select2 selected value in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

i am using multiple numbers of jquery select2

in my html

```
<select class="select2_demo_3 form-control" style="color: #1c84c6" id="selectSubject" name="selectSubject">
<option value="">Select a Subject</option>
<?php
$query= "SELECT * FROM `tblsubject` WHERE `status`='1'";
$found=mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($found)){
?>
<option value="<?php echo($row['id']);?>"><?php echo($row['subject_name']);?></option>
<?php
}
?>
```

```
<select class="select2_demo_3 form-control" id="selectTopic" name="selectTopic">
<option value="">Select a Topic</option>
<?php
$query= "SELECT * FROM `tbltopic` WHERE `status`='1'";
$found=mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($found)){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo($row['id']);?>"><?php echo($row['topic_name']);?></option>
    <?php
}
?>
```

and so on then in my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".select2_demo_3").select2();
});
```

the problem is though i am giving it in id tag of each select , on inspecting the element i am getting a different id which is being set by jquery internally i think.
[screenshot of inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOgT1.png)

as you can see it shows my given id which is "selectSubject" but when i am writing in my script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var questionType=document.getElementById("selectSubject").value;
    </script>
```

i am getting

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" error

what am i doing wrong? can i get select2 value in javascript? or what is the right way to do it?

AS I AM USING MULTIPLE NUMBERS OF SELECT2 I WANT INDIVIDUAL SELECT VALUE BY ID OR SOME OTHER WAY.

edited: corrected the id in getElementById to "selectSubject".

Comment: where is `selectQuestionType` id you have `selectTopic` as id in second select!!

Comment: @Sanchit Patiyal, sorry that was a silly mistake. i have changed it to the correct id "selectSubject" but still getting the same error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Comment: you are writing script before the body or after the body tag??

Comment: @Sanchit Patiyal thanks a lot . it was very very silly of me, i was calling my js before body tag and jquery after body tag. now its working perfectly.thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" error` because your script is running before you DOM is getting loaded. So due to which when the script runs it can't find the Element resulting into `document.getElementById("selectSubject")` as null value. Moving your script part after the body will solve your problem.

```html
<script>
  console.log("script before body tag: %o", document.getElementById("test")); // null
</script>
<div id="test">Hello World</div>
<script>
  console.log("script afterbody tag: %o", document.getElementById("test")); // <div id="test" ...
</script>
```